# WP_Widget_Media_Image::render_media - как корректно заменить функцию?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На сайте с WooCommerce есть изображения, находящиеся по пути `/images/{post_url}/`
Нужно реализовать логику, которая предусматривает вывод изображения, если таковой файл существует. Если не существует, выводится изображение товара, если оно указано - словом, стандартное поведение.

### Вопросы:

Есть ли какие-то хуки, которые можно использовать? И вообще, как лучше/правильней реализовать это?

Пишу свой первый плагин, прошу помощи. Спасибо!

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1. Для начала изучи что такое медиатека и усвой, что в целом ВП работает не с физическими, а логическими сущностями. (причем тут левый каталог с картинками?) 2. А если не найдено, то что выводить?

Comment: Спасибо, поправил вопрос.
1. Примера привести не могу, так как даже примерно не понимаю, с чего начинать..
2. Логику WP ломать не хочу, но нужна интеграция с внешними инструментами. Там простейшие скрипты и даже не скрипты (вручную через FTP выкладываются изображения), которые я изменить не могу.

Comment: ВП ничего не знает о то что мимо него выкладывается на ФТП. Ещё раз - учи как работает медиатека ВП.  И.. что за бред в последнем предложении первого абзаца? Напиши логику на понятном языке.

Comment: Ещё раз: я об этом и говорил, люди выкладывают фото в соответствии с URL товара. Мне надо НАУЧИТЬ WP не выводить медиатеку в определённом товаре, для которого уже есть изображения. Неужели непонятна логика?